# Hi, I want to add required true validation when i am trying to edit cell in vue 3

Tags: ag-grid-vue

I am using below column
{
headerName: 'Account Name',
field: 'account_name',
editable: true,
cellEditor: 'agTextCellEditor',
cellEditorParams: { maxLength: 20 },
},

I tried below settings but it's not workes
{
headerName: 'Account Name',
field: 'account_name',
editable: true,
cellEditor: 'agTextCellEditor',
cellEditorParams: { maxLength: 20, required: true },
},